# Swift 5 - Facebook Login: LoginManager() always return cancelled

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I follow this [tutorial](http://www.wepstech.com/integrate-facebook-login-for-ios/) and I got this error msg from xcode, please help.

> FBSDKLog: There is already a request for authenticated session. Cancelling active SFAuthenticationSession before starting the new one.

Comment: please show us your code not the tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following...

```
let manager = LoginManager() // create object of LoginManager class
manager.logOut() //<- Logout if there is any existing session
manager.logIn(permissions: ["public_profile", "email"], from: self) { (result, error) in


   //your code goes here...

}
```

Comment: hi Dharmesh, it works for the first time only but thank you for the reply

Comment: Faccing same issue can anyone help with workaorund ?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/61803093/2703050 if it can halp on ios 13

Answer (score 0):

The `FBLoginButton` automatically starts the authentication session. Make sure you aren't calling  `FBSDKLoginKit.LoginManager().login()` as a part of your button action. Instead, conform to `LoginButtonDelegate` to handle the result from the authentication session that results from the button tap.